# Mid point in divide and conquer algorithm implementations

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I've seen many implementations using below to find mid point of two indices:

```
int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
```

instead of

```
int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
```

Mathematically, I see no difference and yet, I've never seen anyone using the below one. Is there a difference between the two computationally?

Comment: Then you simply have not seen much.

Comment: You can try lo = 1, hi = 2147483647.

Comment: And this [oldie, but goodie](https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Comment: @cricket_007 Ta muchly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist a maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer in computing.

We assume this value is 100.

```
int lo = 60;
int hi = 80;
```

then `lo + hi = 60 + 80 = 140` **>** `100`, it is dangerous to do so because it will cause a [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) error.

Comment: "it will cause a integer overflow error" Integer overflow isn't really an error, is it? It's just the way computers handle the erroneous situation of a number requiring too many bits to represent.